# BeautifulSoup Absoute URLs Print to CSV

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

I've been going through tons of threads on here to see if I can find a way to fix this code but cant quite seem to get this to work. I'm trying to scrape links from a site  then write to csv. Here's the code:

I found a way to get 95% of the way there but am missing something for getting just the href:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib.request
    import urllib.parse
    import csv

    j = urllib.request.urlopen("http://cnn.com")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(j, "lxml") 
    data = soup.find_all('a', href=True)

    for url in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
#print(url.get('href'))

        with open('marcel.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
            write = csv.writer(csvfile)
            write.writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is probably what you want to do.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests #better than urllib
import csv

j = requests.get("http://cnn.com").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(j, "lxml") 

data = []
for url in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(url['href'])
    data.append(url['href'])

print(data)

with open("marcel.csv",'w') as csvfile:
    write = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter = ' ')
    write.writerows(data)
```

Comment: That Solved it! Thanks :) and just for understanding purposes, adding data = [] means?

Comment: This simply means "create an empty list named in this case data". In this way we can use the .append method to fill it in the loop (this method does not work if the list does not exist yet)

Comment: Is there a way to get only unique values in the output? What I'm hoping to get is a list of the absolute links e.g http://cnn.com/(the scraped url here). But a list with no duplicate values.

Comment: Just add `data = set(data)` before the `with`. To get absolute links, use a `if`statement to concatenate `http://edition.cnn.com/` + each link that starts with a `/`.

Answer (score 0):

I use `openpyxl` to get it

```
from openpyxl import Workbook,load_workbook
```

I think it is very easy.
it is a part of my project,you could try it

```
    def createExcel(self):
        wb = Workbook(optimized_write=True)
        ws = wb.create_sheet(title='书籍列表')
        row0 = ['编号','条码号','题名','责任者','借阅日期','归还日期','馆藏地']
        ws.append(row0)
        save_path = 'book_hist.xlsx'
        wb.save(save_path)

    def saveToExcel(self,data_list):
        wb = load_workbook(filename='book_hist.xlsx')
        ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('书籍列表')
        for i in range(len(data_list)):
            ws.append(data_list[i])
        save_path = 'book_hist.xlsx'
        wb.save(save_path)
```

Comment: sorry,maybe I misunderstood your words

Comment: Ok so I figured out how to get 95% of the way there. Here's what I changed: